# rails 3 route alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In older version 2.x I was doing something like:

```
map.resources :jobs, :as => 'vagas'
```

and this way, I can use jobs_path to create a link to.

But in rails 3, I still can use :as to define an alias, but I cannot
use jobs_path anymore, because it forces me to use vagas_path.

So I was wondering if have any way to define an alias and still use
the original resource name to create a link.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
resources :jobs, :path => 'vagas'  # after the original!
```

Comment: I've found about :path parameter, just forgot to come back here to update my post. But I'll validate your help as a correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

'map' is in Rails 2.x

You should:

```
resources :jobs, :path => :vagas
```